# Login and Register doesnt work, which is rendered from _LoginPartial.cshtml using asp.net core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-5.0

I am new to the ASP.Net Core 5.0 still learning.
As mentioned on the microsoft documentation I have used 
but for some reason it doesnt work. The ConfirgurationServices in Start up file is up to date based on the document

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext.TestDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<TestDbContext>();
    }
```

I have added

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();      
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I have added the `<partial name="_LoginPartial"/>` on the layout page

Here I was expecting the template for the login and register to display when I run the project but   nothing happens when I click the login or register.

how do I work around this?

Comment: Can you share your layout page code please? Perhaps the partial was put in a place that doesn't allow it to be shown.

Comment: If you click on this link you will see the layout page : https://jsfiddle.net/yrvzjcwt/

Comment: Hi @favanimeamir, it seems the partial view has been rendered, right? It just did nothing when you click the login/register button, right? Did you create the project with individual account? If you just create a simple mvc project without individual account it will not contain Identity template.  Besides, if you create project with individual account, the template will contains `Areas/Identity/Pages` folder by default. Please share more details.

Comment: @favanimeamir It seems to be working for me when I copied your layout over. Though I haven't logged in with it, the partial is rendering and the links are working. To double check, the links in the partial are rendering in the navbar, but nothing happens when you click them?

Answer (score 0):

_LoginPartial is using RazorPages, so in program.cs you have to call app.MapRazorPages(); after the MapControllerRoute